# Ionic + background mode + BLE doesnt catch BLE events

Tags: android, ionic-framework, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

Good morning

Im developing in inonic (im doesnt have much experience on this framework) and app that should catch a BLE event in background.

Im using these libraries:

https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

My problem is, that in foreground it works without problems, it catchs the event perfectly. But when I move it to the background, the app is still working but when I launch the event this is "paused".

What it means? I can press a button in my ble device (for example) with the app in background, and this doesnt work , but if (without press the ble device again) move the app to foreground ,atomatically it starts to do the event that it shoulds did just in the momment when is pressed the ble device.

¿Someone knows how to solve it?

If u need more information or code will be a pleasure to provide it.

Thanks

Comment: There is an example project that shows how to use your plugin in background mode: https://github.com/don/ble-background maybe you find something that helps you

Comment: thank u @M.Kotzjan, I will check it :)